# capturing user input in rails and querying it in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller called Welcome with a view called index which contains a small form where user can enter longitude , latitude values in a text field.

Here is the code in index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :welcome do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :longitude %><br>

    <%= f.text_field :longitude %>
    <br>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :latitude %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :latitude %>


  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Once the user enters the longitude and latitude value i try to capture them in the welcome controller. Here is the code for that.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @long = params[:longitude]
     @lat =  params[:latitude]
  end


end
```

Following is my routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  post 'welcome/index'
end
```

I have a table called stop. Inside it there is pre populated data for a stop including a id, name, longitude and a latitude.

**What i want to achieve** 
So basically i want to do a small check where i do a query to find the stop id of a stop that has the matching longitude and latitude values entered by the user. Finally I would like to print the that stop id on my index.html.erb page

**The issue i am facing**
So for example in the small form i created. Say i type in value "123" for longitude field and "456" for latitude field. After i click submit I see the following in my terminal

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"N7RssIp7sQggxZ2RArEf9CnrUYXK6aG7Ix1MJlI5MoEPDocATHjXdlo24w0gFCTG+4B43ks0sVx1XNlS3RO84Q==", "welcome"=>{"longitude"=>"123", "latitude"=>"456"}, "commit"=>"Save Welcome"}
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (33.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 108ms (Views: 107.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

However in my welcome controller when i do the following

```
Stop.find_by longitude: '@long'
```

I see this in terminal

```
Stop Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `stops`.* FROM `stops` WHERE `stops`.`longitude` = 0 LIMIT 1
```

From this it is obvious i am not capturing the user inputs correctly. Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

I know there are better ways of getting locations etc but i am just learning rails and it is vital i understand the basics of doing such things. Please let me know if anything is unclear. I have tried to resolve this for past 2 days without luck i would highly appreciate answer to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form_for is a model back form, which means that you need to pass it an object of one of your model which has a longitude and latitude parameters. In this case, you don't have that, so you should use form_tag instead:

```
<%= form_tag("/welcome/index", method: "post") do %>
  <%= label_tag :longitude %><br>
  <%= text_field_tag :longitude %>
  <br>
  <br>
  <%= label_tag :latitude %><br>
  <%= text_field_tag :latitude %>
  <p>
    <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Now your routes need a little fixing.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index', to: 'welcome#index'
  post 'welcome/index', to: 'welcome#create'
  get 'welcome/new', to: 'welcome#new'
end
```

You need 2 different pages, the new page to display the inputs for longitude and latitude, and the index to display your stop information. Now your controller should look like this

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  # displays the form, so change the name of the form you have now to new.html.erb
  def new
  end

  # the form will pass to this action to perform logic on longitude and latitude
  def create
    longitude = params[:longitude]
    latitude = params[:latitude]
    @stops = Stop.where("longitude = ? AND latitude = ?", longitude, latitude)
    render :index
  end

  # if it renders from the create action, @stops will be available to use here
  def index
  end
end
```

Now in your index.html.erb file, display the stop ids that are matched with the users input of longitude and latitude

```
<% if @stops %>
  <% @stops.each do |stop| %>
    <p>
      stop id: #{stop.id}<br>
      latitude: #{stop.latitude}<br>
      longitude: #{stop.longitude}
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This looks very promising i will try it right now. Thank you so much for your efforts !!! God bless you.

Comment: So When you do the following @stops = Stop.where("longitude = ? AND latitude = ?", longitude, latitude)   . Is @ stops an array?

Comment: Yes, it returns an array of stops that has the matching longitude and latitude, whether it finds 0, 1, or more.

Comment: Okay that clears it up now for example in my stop table i have name field, longitude field, latitude field and id field. And i want to print any of those fields would i do #{stop.name} or something because at the moment when there is a match it is simply outputting stop.id on the page. So  i know the logic is correct just want to print the actual ID now instead of 'stop.id'

Comment: I tried your new edit but for some reason it is still showing plain text
  stop id: #{stop.id}<br>
      latitude: #{stop.latitude}<br>
      longitude: #{stop.longitude}

Comment: I think there is some syntax error or maybe missing something

Comment: Thanks a lot i just had final question. Why did you use def create function why couldnt we write the code to capture user input under def index function ?

Comment: You're already using the index method to display the form. What you can do though is get rid of the new method and combine that with the index method and move the stuff in new.html.erb into index.html.erb

Comment: Thanks, so do each method in the controller such as new create represent a view page ? for example should i have a create.html.erb page for the create method?

Comment: No, its rendering the index template. Generally when you post to a controller action, you want to render another template or redirect to another url.

Comment: can you recommend any tutorial video or something where i can learn more a  bout the interaction between the controllers and the view and vice versa? i understand the db and model part well.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try to use `params[:welcome][:longitude]` **instead of** `params[:longitude]`

**Also** try `Stop.find_by longitude: "'#{@long}'"` **instead of** `Stop.find_by longitude: '@long'`

Comment: when i try params[:welcome][:longitude] i get undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass